# RxJava2 Convert Flowable to Single

Tags: android, rx-java2

How do I convert a Flowable to a Single? Or if there's another way to make it stop emitting after the first response that is also of interest.

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
  disposables.add(
        repository.getAllSomethings()
           .subscribeOn(SchedulerProvider.getInstance().computation())
           .observeOn(SchedulerProvider.getInstance().ui())
           .toSingle()
           .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<List<Something>>() {
                override fun onSuccess(t: List<Something>) {
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                }
            })
```

getAllSomethings() returns a `Flowable<List<Something>>`

In the above code `.subscribeWith()` is underlined in red complaining that:

```
Type parameter bound for E in 
fun <E : SingleObserver<in Flowable<List<Something>!>!>!> subscribeWith(observer: E!): E!
is not satisfied: inferred type  ! is not a subtype of SingleObserver<in Flowable<List<Something>!>!>!
```

Comment: I suggest you familiarize yourself with the [available operators](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html) - which will save you a lot of time.

Comment: ok so I guess you're saying I should use single(T defaultItem)? But I don't want to return a defaultItem. It should emit a single value or timeout and call the onError.

Comment: Keep looking at the available operators.

Comment: ok I got it. or at least it seems to work with firstOrError(). thanks for your advice! do you want to answer it or should I do it? I actually remember you from a previous post and you wanted me to do the answer as you didn't care about points.

Comment: You found it, you post an answer. There are plenty of questions on SO requiring a non-trivial set of operators to solve and points to acquire.

Comment: yes I found it but with your help (and you knew the answer). I felt obliged to ask, however I'll take this to mean that if you ever answer like that again that this is what you want. Thanks again.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ok so thanks to @akarnokd I found the answer as you can see in the comments.

Teaching me how to fish rather than giving me the straight answer he suggested looking here: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html (which really I should have done in the first place!).

Looking there I found `firstOrError()` which solves my problem.

Even though the object I was calling `toSingle()` from was a Flowable, the IDE didn't complain. Yet looking at the link above, `toSingle()` isn't even a valid option!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I actually had a Flowable and wanted the benefits of that (i.e. backpressure), but I still wanted to return a `Single`, e.g. `Single<List<String>>`. In my case, I was using Android WorkManager's `RxWorker` which expects my function to return `Single<Result>`, not a Flowable.

In this case,

```kotlin
val flowable = Flowable.just("my flowable")
return flowable.toList() // type: Single<List<String>>
```

or if you wanted to return a specific value because you don't care about the flowable output:

```kotlin
return flowable.toList().map {} // returns unit
return flowable.toList().map { "Hello" } // returns String
return flowable.toList().map { Result.success() } // returns Result
```